# About $n^{th}$ order Fibonacci sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, fibonacci-numbers

A Fibonacci sequence of order n is an integer sequence in which each sequence element is the sum of the previous $n$ elements (with the exception of the first $n$ elements in the sequence)
Let us denote $k^{th}$ term by $F^{n}_k$ and it is natural to define $F^{n}_k= 2^{k-1}$ for $k < n$. So under these conditions it is interesting to note that these sequences occur in composition of integers. This is what Wikipedia says

> The number of compositions of nonnegative integers into parts that are at most $n$ is a Fibonacci sequence of order $n$.

I have figured out a proof for this which is actually not really difficult to do. But I am not able to find anything in literature. In Wikipedia also no reference is mentioned. In OEIS also some specific sequences are listed but I am not able to find any general argument. Can anyone suggest some articles?

Edit:

Outline of the proof that I have thought:
This is just a heuristic argument and can be made more precise.

Let $f_k$ denote number of solutions to the equation
$$ a_1+ a_2 + \cdots + a_j = k$$ where $1\le a_i \le n $ for each $i$. If $k \le n $ then the problem is nothing but finding number of composition of $k$ which is nothing but $2^{k-1}$ (which is well-known).So we consider $k  > n$. We observe that the above equation can be written as
$$ b + a_1 + \cdots + a_{i-1} + a_{i+1} + \cdots + a_j = k - r $$ where $b = a_i - r$ for each possible$i$ and $1 \le r < n $. So the above equation has $f_{k-r} $ solutions for each $r$ and so we have $f_k = f_{k-1} + \cdots + f_{k - n +1} $ which finishes our argument and we conclude that $f_k$ is nothing but $k^{th}$ term of $n^{th}$ order Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Are you asking for an alternative proof of the statement? If so, can you add/sketch your current proof?

Comment: "Can anyone suggest something?": yes, show us.

Comment: @Calvin Lin I am not asking alternative proofs but any literature or references related to the above matter.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I edited the question for more clarity, thanks for your concern.

Comment: It is an almost immediate result, esp by A) Induction/Bijection, or B) Generating Functions. You might not find it in the literature as stated, because the "base case" of the Fibonacci sequence of order 2 is the main one of interest, and the order $n$ is a easily generalizable result. You might see it as an exercise in a textbook. As such, I suggest that you either A) State your proof, or B) Explain what other type of information you're wanting to know.

Comment: @Calvin Lin I have given the outline of the argument